# ASP.NET MVC 4 Routing For Specific Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following controller/action:

```
public class SomeThingController
{
     IEnumerable<SomeThing> Search(DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate, bool summaryOnly = true){}
}
```

The idea would be that summaryOnly parameter doesn't have to be specified, but minDate and maxDate must be.

Can someone offer routes for the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following route:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Search",
            routeTemplate: "api/search/{minDate}/{maxDate}/{summaryOnly}",
            defaults: new { 
                summaryOnly = RouteParameter.Optional,  
                controller = "SomeThing", 
                action = "search" 
            }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public class SomeThingController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<SomeThing> Search(DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate, bool summaryOnly = true)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then you could request this endpoint like this:

```
/api/search/2013-02-08/2013-02-10/
```

or:

```
/api/search/2013-02-08/2013-02-10/false
```